# trying to read a text file using cstrings

Tags: arrays, gdb

I'm trying to pull data from a ";" delimited text file using cstrings. I can't use strings for this assignment. My program opens the file okay and reads the first 3 fields and then the input stream enters fail state. Also, using gdb, the value of the first var read in, info[i].songName shows that the song name has been assigned to the var but there are 93 bytes of junk data attached to the end. I'm sure it has something to do with declaring the cstring to have 100 characters but I'm not sure how to deal with having a custom array size for each new line of data in the source file. The program compiles but throws a segmentation fault error when I try to run it, presumably from something that is causing the array to go out of bounds.

Here's the first line of the source file:

```
    Divine;Supreme Beings of Leisure;4;26;Divine Operating System
```

Here's the definition of the struct from the song.h

```
    5 struct song  {
    6     char song_Name[100];
    7     int min;
    8     int sec;
    9     char album[100];
    10    char artist[100];
    11 };
```

...and here's main.cpp

```
    1 //This program tracks a text file list of songs and prompts user to add, delete,
    2 //search the list.
    3
    4 #include "main.h"
    5
    6
    7
    8 int main()  {
    9
    10     int size = 0;
    11     int i = 0;
    12     ifstream infile;
    13     song info[size];
    14
    15     infile.open("songs.txt");
    16     while (!infile.is_open())   {
    17         cout << "File not found" << endl;
    18         return 1;
    19     }
    20
    21     while (!infile.eof())   {
    22         infile.getline(info[i].song_Name, 100, ';');
    23         infile.ignore();
    24         infile.getline(info[i].artist,100,';');
    25         infile >> info[i].min;
    26         infile.clear();
    27         infile  >> info[i].sec;
    28         infile.clear();
    29         infile.getline(info[i].album, 100, ';');
    30         i++;
    31 }
    32
    33     for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    34         cout << info[i].song_Name << " "
    35              << info[i].min << " " << info[i].sec << " "
    36              << info[i].album << " " << info[i].artist << endl;
    37 }
    38
    39
    40  
    41 song add (char songN[100],int min, int sec, char album[100], char artist[]);
    42     return 0;
```

and...finally...here's the value of the vars for the first line as reported by gdb...

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:21
21              while (!infile.eof())   {
(gdb) n
22                      infile.getline(info[i].song_Name, 100, ';');
(gdb) n
23                      infile.getline(info[i].artist,100,';');
(gdb) n
24                      infile >> info[i].min;
(gdb) n
25                      infile.clear();
(gdb) n
26                      infile.clear();
(gdb) n
27                      infile  >> info[i].sec;
(gdb) n
28                      infile.clear();
(gdb) n
29                      infile.clear();
(gdb) n
30                      infile.getline(info[i].album, 100, ';');
(gdb) n
31                      i++;
(gdb) p info[i].song_Name
$1 = "Divine\000\000\243\r@\000\000\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\320\336\377\377\377\177\000\000\020\062\335\367\377\177\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\030\061\335\367\377\177\000\000`Na\000\000\000\000\000\203Na\000\000\000\000\000\232Oa", '\000' <repeats 24 times>
(gdb) p info[i].min
$2 = 4
(gdb) p info[i].sec
$3 = 0
(gdb) p info[i].album
$4 = "\000\177", '\000' <repeats 42 times>, " La\000\000\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b", '\000' <repeats 31 times>, "`Na\000\000\000\000"
(gdb)
```

EDIT: changing song.h to this:

```
        struct song  {
  6     int min;
  7     int sec;
  8     char song_Name[];
  9     char album[];
 10     char artist[];
 11 };
```

...has eliminated the issue with the char vars. song_Name now stores only the chars in the line up to the ";" delimiter. But the code in main on line 24 is breaking the program somehow. It will still compile okay but still throws a segmentation fault and stepping through the code one line at a time shows it breaks at line 24.

Comment: `int size = 0;` followed by `song info[size];` can't work. What did you expect to happen with an empty array?

Comment: Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to see the obvious.